# Compiler ignores object declaration inside a class assumes it to be int

Tags: c++

> I am using Visual Studio for compiling my code and I am pretty new to coding. I have to make an Order class with the object of EAN class as its data member.
>   But when I compile my code it shows an error in the class declaration .
>
> The error is : syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'ean_o'
>
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

```
class Order
{
    int ordered;
    int delivered;
    EAN ean_o;
    bool empty;

public:

    Order();
    Order(const EAN& );
    EAN& getEAN();
    int outstanding() const;
    bool add(std::istream& is);
    bool add(int n);
    bool receive(std::istream& is);
    void display(std::ostream& os) const;



};
```

Comment: What header files did you `#include`?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the header that defines `EAN` isn't being included.

Comment: This class declaration itself is a header file " Order.h". Similarly I have "EAN.h" .

Comment: But I have all my header files included in my main program .

Comment: You need to `#include "EAN.h"` in Order.h, before you use the token `EAN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an Ean class created, you must include it into your Order header

```
#include "Ean.h"
```

The best thing to do is to include Ean.h here and not to not include it in your main.
Once you include Order.h in main, it will get Ean.h from Order.h

Comment: Can you mark my answer as the answer of the question please. Providing you are happy with it!

Comment: Sure I tried, it says  I have to wait for 5 minutes to accept an answer.

Comment: Also, you may want to read up on [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)

Comment: Certain errors may occur if you include headers more than once so these include guards help deal with this